# Extending Spring's pointcut-definig expression language

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I am currently experimenting with Spring and its AOP features.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to extend the expression language of pointcut definition somehow...

I am quite familiar with the standard behaviour and usage of pointcut designators Spring provides but for my needs I would like to implement my own one.

Say we have a method in our aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class AspectClass {

    @Before("execution(* *.get*(..)) && @annotation(someAnnotation)"
    public void doStuff(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, SomeAnnotation someAnnotation) {
        System.out.println("Doing stuff!");
    }
}
```

Now what I would like is something like this:

```
...
@Before("execution(* *.get*(..)) && @myAnnotation(someAnnotation)"
public void doStuff(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, SomeAnnotation someAnnotation){
...
```

Where the `myAnnotation(..)` token is my custom extension of the expression language.

When I delved into Spring implementation I found where the parser resides and the fact it is hard-coded into `AspectJExpressionPointcut` implementation. Hence providing a custom implementation of said parser and sticking it someplace in some bean initialization routine seems like a no-no.

Exemplary usage of this extension would be for example matching a method by it's annotation, disregarding proximity of this annotation in the object hierarchy. So it would match a method that is overriden and whose annotation is defined on the parent's implementation.

```
public abstract class Superclass {
    @SomeAnnotation
    public abstract String getValue();
}

public class TheClass extends Superclass {
    @Override
    public String getValue() { // <- this would get advised by Spring using formerly defined aspect
        // return some stuff
    }
}
```

I know that I can reflect the method in the advice and check if the annotation is present on some method of some superclass, but I would like to encapsulate this process and offer it for convenient usage.

Have you guys stumbled upon something like this & can you offer me a solution (if it is possibe) / explanation (if it is not)? :-)

Thanks in advance, Janek.

Comment: Doubt if this is possible. Like you have mentioned, this specific construct is part of the core AspectJ language and does not appear to be extensible the way you have mentioned it.